# Python Quicksort Implementation with duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, quick-sort

Please critique my implementation of Quicksort in python 3.8:

```
import random
from typing import List


def quicksort(A: List[int], left: int, right: int):
    """
    Sort the array in-place in the range [left, right(
    """
    if left >= right:
        return

    pivot_index = random.randint(left, right - 1)

    swap(A, left, pivot_index)

    pivot_new_index = partition(A, left, right)
    quicksort(A, left, pivot_new_index)
    quicksort(A, pivot_new_index + 1, right)


def partition(A: List[int], left: int, right: int) -> int:
    """
    in-place partition around first item
    """

    if left >= right:
        return left
    pivot = A[left]
    # initialize i, j pointers
    j = left + 1
    while j < right and A[j] <= pivot:
        j += 1
    i = j
    # invariant :
    # A[left+1 ... i-1] <= pivot
    # A[i ... j-1] > pivot
    # A[j ... right( unexplored
    while j < right:
        if A[j] <= pivot:
            swap(A, i, j)
            i += 1
        j += 1

    swap(A, left, i - 1)
    return i - 1


def swap(A: List[int], i: int, j: int):
    A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
```

I followed Tim Roughgarden's explanations in his MOOC on algorithms. But he assumes the keys are all distinct and says that having Quicksort work efficiently on many duplicated keys is trickier than it seems and point to Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne book on algorithms. I checked it and the partition method looks indeed way different.

My current code seems to work even with duplicated keys but I think if all the keys are the same, I will get a O(n²) complexity (partitioned arrays will be very unbalanced). How can I update my current code to address this issue?

Comment: (Please do *not* change in your code (after the first CR answer): when using round *and* square brackets for the notation of intervals, they are in standard orientation. I've seen mirrored ones when using (round) parentheses exclusively.)

Comment: (*Dual pivot* is superior to *three way (<,=,>) partition*.)

Answer (score 2):

Performance problems with quicksort are due to one single partition getting almost all of the items, incurring repeated "partition cost".
In the extreme (undetected, if for sake of argument) case of *all equal keys*, the code presented (implementing [Lomuto's partition scheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme)) puts all items equal to pivot in the left partition, returning the index of the rightmost one, leading to quadratic time.
Careful implementations of Hoare partition move values equal to pivot to "the other partition", resulting in a balanced split here.
(When implementing dual pivot, checking they differ seems prudent.)

The minimally invasive change would seem to be to change the way values equal to pivot are handled - *either*

- Keep a toggle indicating where to put the next one - *or*
- Put the item in the partition currently smaller.

  ```
  if A[j] <  pivot or (
     A[j] == pivot and i-left < j-i):
  ```

---

- Why restrict items to `int`?
- Most of the implementation looks minimalistic (down to function docstrings, only -  without full-stops).
  The special handling of values not exceeding pivot before the main loop of `partition()` doesn't quite seem in line.
- While you can put pivot selection in `partition()` just as well as in `quicksort()`, you could put it in a function of its own to emphasize mutual independance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to handle duplicates without a big performance degrade is to randomly shuffle the input list before doing the sort. A specific algorithm to do so is a Fisher Yates Shuffle.

Comment: What does shuffling duplicates achieve?

Comment: This allows expected complexity to be stated which does not depend on the algorithms input

Comment: (When some information has not been just overlooked by a commenter, add the elaboration to your post rather than commenting a comment.)

Comment: Did you notice the `quicksort()` presented already tries to evade *systematic bad choice of pivot value*: `pivot_index = random.randint(left, right - 1)`? This doesn't help coping with *significantly fewer key values than items* - neither does shuffling.